# Plot scanpath onto image

Tags: python, r, matlab, plot

I have an image and a .txt file of gaze fixations in x, y coordinates. I want to plot the scanpath of fixations onto the image using the .txt file.  Is there a way to do this in R or Matlab? (Or python).

This data was not collected using a standard eye tracker (like Eyelink or Tobii). Ideally the method would also allow me to vary the size of the fixation dot by the fixation duration.

Comment: But otherwise gaze data has some uniform sampling rate? I'm guessing your want to show (superpose) track over 'what they were looking at'?

Comment: The sampling rate is uniform, but I was planning to use the cleaned fixation data for plotting (not a video, which would need frame by frame, but just a simple overlay). So fixation 1 : 10, 100 (200ms); fixation 2 : 50, 200 (400ms), etc.

Comment: You probably don't want the fixation dot to grow by location as it will obscure location. There are a bunch of R packages that deal with eye tracking that don't presume you

Comment: You probably don't want the fixation dot to grow by location as it will obscure location. Don't waste your time with the proprietary equipment packages, take a look at cran LPTime. Best one I ran across, saccades by marlsburg is also worth, but the rest are equipment/file structure dependent when you just want to think about fixations. So, fixate there.

Comment: LPTime is a cool package generally so I'm glad to know about it, but I already have the cleaned data using an in-house algorithm to detect fixations. My main interest is plotting and neither package seems to have a plotting function.